# JQuery datepicker 'undefined' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I want search another query on my view with datepicker, using **`$.ajax({})`** and I doing click on datepicker after AJAX request, show me message `'undefined' is null or not an object`.

Code datepicker JS,

```
$("#datepicker_tx").datepicker({
     showOn: 'button',
     buttonImageOnly: true,
     buttonImage: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/calendar.png'
})
```

My code HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv"><input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker_tx" size="20" value="${dayT}" /></div>
```

My code JS is next:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'getSearchResult?action=getSearchResult',
   data: 'val1=' + val1 + 'val2=' + val2 + 'val3=' + val3,
   cache: false,
   success: function(data) {
      var jqObj = JQuery(data);
      jqObj.find('div#div1').remove();
      $("div#div2").empty().append(jqObj);
   }
})
```

Comment: `JQuery(data)` should be `jQuery(data)` or `$(data)`. And your `data` option should be like `'val1=' + val1 + '&val2=' + val2 + '&val3=' + val3`

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
var jqObj = JQuery(data);
```

I'm not sure what `data` contains, but either you can use `data` directly, or it's a selector that can be used like `var jqObj = $(data)`.

It's safe to first find out what `data` contains by using `console.log(data)`.

Comment: No, didn't work. data contains HTML after `ajax` request in 2 div, on div1 contain datepicker button and div2 I show response rest.

Comment: @hekomobile I'm sure the error message also tells you exactly WHERE the error occurs?